# Slicing a matlab cell

Tags: matlab

```
a_1 = 1;
a_2 = sqrt(0.1);
l = -10:10;
t = 1e-6;
N = 10^6 ;
SNR = 0:10; % Valeurs du SNR en dB
a = 1/sqrt(2) ;
Es = 2*a^2 ; 
QPSK = [1+1i, 1-1i, -1-1i, -1+1i];
X_QPSK = sqrt(Es/2)*(QPSK(randi(length(QPSK),1,N)));

W = [0, 250000,50000, 500000, 1000000] ; % Vecteur des frequences

H = cell(zeros(1,length(W))) ; 
Vecteur_convolution = cell(zeros(1,length(W))) ; % convolution output
Sortie = cell(zeros(1,length(W))) ;
h0 = a_1*sinc(l)+ a_2*sinc(l-t*W(1));
h1 = a_1*sinc(l)+ a_2*sinc(l-t*W(2));
h2 = a_1*sinc(l)+ a_2*sinc(l-t*W(3));
h3 = a_1*sinc(l)+ a_2*sinc(l-t*W(4));
h4 = a_1*sinc(l)+ a_2*sinc(l-t*W(5));

H{1,1} = h0 ;
H{1,2} = h1 ;
H{1,3} = h2 ;
H{1,4} = h3; 
H{1,5} = h4; 

for i = 1:length(W)    
    Vecteur_convolution{1,i} = conv(X_QPSK, H{i}) ;  
    Sortie{1,i} =  Vecteur_convolution{i(10:lenght(X_QPSK ))} % Not correct
end



% By the way, if I write it like this, it works. But I'm trying to make it compact if possible

Sconv0 = conv(x_QPSK,h0);
S0 = Sconv0(length(SNR):length(SNR)+length(X_QPSK) - 1);

% Pour W = 50 KHz
Sconv50K = conv(x_QPSK,h1);
S50K = Sconv50K(length(SNR):length(SNR)+length(X_QPSK) - 1);

% Pour W = 250 KHz
Sconv250K = conv(x_QPSK,h2);
S250K = Sconv250K(length(SNR):length(SNR)+length(X_QPSK) - 1);

% Pour W = 500 KHz
Sconv500K = conv(x_QPSK,h3);
S500K = Sconv500K(length(SNR):length(SNR)+length(X_QPSK) - 1);

% Pour W = 1 MHz
Sconv1M = conv(x_QPSK,4);
S1M = Sconv1M(length(SNR):length(SNR)+length(X_QPSK) - 1);
```

Good morning folks. I'm not sure what I'm trying to do is possible in Matlab, but here it goes. I'm doing a convolution and storing the output in " Vecteur_convolution", so it's a 1x5 cell. Because the convolution increases the number of points, I only want to retrieve my sample number back (1.000.000) instead of (1000010) and store it into the "Sortie" 1x5 cell.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure, if i get your question right, but aren't you just looking for an interpolation? If so, you could try using `interp1`-function

Comment: You can try [conv](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv.html) with options `'same'` or `'valid'`.

Comment: Thank you. That is what I was trying to do this whole time.  'same' solved it.